# Query error: #1833 - Cannot change column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Al mometo de ingresar datos a la tabla ingresos me sale el error:

**QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:1364 Field 'idingreso' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ingreso` (`idproveedor`, `tipo_comprobante`, `serie_comprobante`, `num_comprobante`, `fecha_hora`, `impuesto`, `estado`) values (9, Boleta, 002, 003, 2019-09-20 04:35:25, 18, A))**

Y a su vez idingreso tiene una llave foranea con la tabla detalle_ingreso por lo que al momeno de asignarle un valor no lo permite por que ambos campos deben tener el mismo tipo de datos, idingresoso de la tabla ingresos y idingresos de la llave forea en la tabla detalle ingresos.

esta es la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de la migracion

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

codigo tabla ingresos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No le estas pasando ningun valor a `idingreso`, ni es autoincrement, por eso te retorna error de que no tiene ningun valor por defecto. Agrega mocomo tienes la migracion de esa tabla por que seguramente tengas mal definido ese campo.

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta soy principiante en esto, ya habia tratado de poner el auto incremento o establecer valor por default "0" pero no me lo premite habia visto algo como quitar permisos de mysql no se si sea mas conveniente he seguido el curso al pie de la letra pero no bien explicado no se en que momento cree la tabla migraciones o para que es.

Comment: Un valor por defacto al ser PK no te va a dejar, edita la pregunta y agrega el código php de la migración de la tabla buscalo en `/database/migrations` o el `SHOW CREATE TABLE ingreso` para que entendamos mejor como esta creada la tabla.

Comment: El código que pusiste es de una migración que no veo tenga que ver con el mensaje de error que te sale

Comment: @AugustC. Entiendo que no estas utilizando las migraciones de Laravel si no que creas las tablas con tu DBMS. Como imaginaba y segun se ve en con el SHOW CREATE TABLE el PK de `ingreso` no es AUTOINCREMENT, debes hacer que sea autoincrement, para esto es posible que tengas que eliminar primero las relaciones, hacer la modificacion y volver a añadir las reaciones. Te recomiendo que ya que utilizas Laravel aproveches las migraciones, ayudan mucho con modificaciones sobretodo en desarrollo y facilita buenas practicas: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations